# Improve touchscreen handling on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8

I am working on a web app that will be run off a local server on Windows 8 on Chrome. Unfortunately, Chrome doesn't seem to handle touch events very well. For example, often instead of clicking on a button, it will select it instead. Is there any way I can make it behave more like native touchscreen apps do?

I can't make it a metro app because I need to talk to a Python service.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some testing in Chrome with a touch screen and don't seem to run into this issue (of course not doubting you are though!). If you have a site I'd be more than happy to check it out.

One option is to try scaling the content larger, I'm wondering if your touch surface is very sensitive to tiny movements upon touch and treating it as a touch/scroll ie select. Try a simple test in the browser to start by increasing the size before trying any css scaling transforms (which I'm not sure how in this how well that approach would even work)

What type of hardware is it being tested on?

Can you elaborate a bit more on the python service? What part of the service makes it so you can't interact with it? Is it just an http service object or something else?

Comment: Well, that is exactly the problem. It is too easy to do a select rather than a click.

We've got some new Acer Iconia tablets. The Python service is a wrapper over drivers for a device. It returns JSON via HTTP

Comment: Why then can't you make a win8 app? You dot have a cross domain restriction for Ajax data from your local pages (called the local context as opposed to the web context for pages outside if your apps package)